# Arduino compatible GPS modules with support for GAGAN SBAS and 10Hz rate support

Tags: hardware, sbas

Looking for an Arduino compatible GPS module that supports:
- GAGAN SBAS
AND
- 10Hz update rate

Any suggestions? Not able to find one that meets both requirements.

Comment: Whether Apple IPhone also supports S-BAs through GAGAN?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... I came across your post quite late... Am posting some of my GAGAN and GNSS sensor related findings and though not directly related to Arduino hope they are of use to you or someone else.

As per the technical literature available on GAGAN, it is compatible with other SBASes (WAAS, EGNOS, MSAS etc). I carried out testing with multiple Android mobile/tablet devices with GNSS support using the OS APIs. All that support GNSS seem to report GAGAN as well. Following was the result:

1. Google Nexus 7 2013 - It reports PRN 127 & 128 (NMEA ID 40, 41) which are GSAT-8 and GSAT-10 respectively of GAGAN. This is apart from EGNOS and MSAS which it also reports. However, it does not seem to get a fix on either and only reports them as available/visible. Also the SV azimuth and elevation is also not reported.
2. Motorola Defy+ - It reports only PRN 127 though it also reports EGNOS and MSAS. Strangely the azimuth and elevation of the SV reported is quite off and actually puts GSAT-8 at 63.5°E. It also reports only as available/visible.
3. Samsung Galaxy S2+ - It reports only QZSS and also reports it being used (of doubtful use in India). Which neither of the others do. Also the SV azimuth and elevation is reported with correct values.
4. Sony Xperia M - It reports both the GAGAN SVs apart. As per the reporting information it is using GSAT-10! Here, the SV azimuth and elevation is not reported.

So in conclusion GAGAN support shall depend only on a GNSS module which supports SBAS. The issue of QZSS support and availability of azimuth/elevation data is strange. So support/implementation may vary from vendor to vendor.

Again, hope this is of use. Would love to hear your experience with GAGAN...

Comment: Thanks Kanchu. 
I kind of gave up on GAGAN. I do use a module from GlobalTech (http://www.gtop-tech.com/en/product/MT3339_GPS_Module_04.html) that supports SBAS (though GAGAN support is claimed to be 'coming soon').
BTW as a side question -- do you have any experience with any kind of GPS 'bad' data filtering? (anything from from simpler algos to elaborate sensor fusion using GPS+accel+gyro) I would really appreciate some help/guidance. Please let me know if you have any experience, then we can either take this up on another thread or offline. 
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry O.K. ... My interest with GAGAN is with regards to development of an Android app. Mobile/tablet device GNSS sensors already output information after filtering so further filtering is not recommended so no experience. As for GAGAN just look out for PRN 127 & 128 (NMEA ID 40, 41) with your module. Not sure how exactly it would be done but should require processing NMEA sentences, which I'm sure the module would be outputting...

Comment: Thanks. Yes the module outputs NMEA. I'll check out the IDs you mentioned. I'll post my findings when I explore this GAGAN stuff on my module.